# Proving a general formula for $\sum_{m=0}^{n}(-1)^m\binom{n}{m} \sin(a+(n-m)h)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

While solving some of limits questions I noticed a very remarkable formula popping up which I think is pretty interesting. But I am not able to prove the formula with general values of $n$. The formula goes as follows

> $$\begin{align}\phi(0)\sin (a+nh)&-\phi (1)\sin [a+(n-1)h] \\
> &+\phi (2)\sin [a+(n-2)h]\\
> &-\cdots \\
> &+(-1)^n\sin (a) \\
> &=
> \begin{cases}
> -2^n\sin^n\left(\frac h2\right)\sin \left(a+\frac {nh}{2}\right) ,  & \text{if $n=4k-2$ $\forall k\in N$} \\[2ex]
> \phantom{-}2^n\sin^n\left(\frac h2\right)\sin \left(a+\frac {nh}{2}\right)  , & \text{if $n=4k\phantom{+0\;}$ $\forall k\in N$ }  \\[2ex]
> -2^n\sin^n\left(\frac h2\right)\cos \left(a+\frac {nh}{2}\right) ,  & \text{if $n=4k-1$ $\forall k\in N$} \\[2ex]
> \phantom{-}2^n\sin^n\left(\frac h2\right)\cos \left(a+\frac {nh}{2}\right) ,  & \text{if $n=4k+1$ $\forall k\in N$} \\[2ex]
> \end{cases}
> \end{align}$$
>
> Where $\phi(m)=\binom {n}{m}$ and $n\ge m$, and $n, m\in Z$ and $n\gt 1$

Any resources like PDF or book name are also welcome

Edit:

I used the complex numbers as per the hint but still I am not able to expand it . As per the hint we need to find $$\Im (e^{ia}(e^{ih}-1)^n) =\Im(e^{ia}[(\cos (h) -1)+i\sin h]^n)$$ But I am not able to use the De Moivre's theorem here as it is. Should there be any algebraic manipulations further?

Comment: Hint: How do you expand $e^{ia}(1-e^{ih})^n$?

Comment: @BAI Do you mean $\Im [e^{ia}(e^{ih}-1)^n]$

Comment: yes, of course. And the rest are analogous.

Comment: Consider that $(e^{ih}-1)^n$ $=(2ie^{ih/2}\sin (h/2))^n$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thanks a lot for the hint. You must have posted it as an answer so that I could accept it.

Comment: It's late. I think I will leave the details to you. The 4 different cases you have observed come from the term $ i^n$   that occurs in my  RHS, which is $\pm 1$ or $\pm i$ depending on $n$ modulo $4$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yeah as soon as I saw your hint I already saw that coming and hence I completed my proof at that time itself.  Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Whenever I see $e^A-1$ I think of half-angle formulas.